# How to set api key for Google maps v2

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a map application. I am setting up the `AndroidManifest.xml` file for the permissions and `API Key`.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dibya.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.dibya.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <!-- Permissions needed -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.dibya.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="KEY" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am getting an error message:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0`.

You must have the following declaration within the `<application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

I have entered the correct API key. Please tell me where am I making mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the below tag inside your application tag and it works.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need add library Google Play Service . After that there is missing one uses-permission, i.e., `<uses-permission android:name="com.dibya.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />`

Please rewrite the code in this manner:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:normalScreens="true"  
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <permission
          android:name="com.dibya.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.dibya.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
.........
```

I think your problem will be solved.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following metadata in application tag. You have to use updated googlePlayService library(13th Rev).

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Write Android Manifest like this way. I am sure your map will works fine if you don't make any other mistakes.

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.mmmm.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mmmm.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your API Key"/>
```